# Cipher vs. Cypher

Tags: differences

I recently came across a (not very well written) piece of writing in which "cipher" and "cypher" were used interchangeably. Is there any difference between them, or are they two spellings of the exact same word? If so, is it similar to the difference between the words "gray" and "grey", where one is more common in a certain geographic area?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Oxford Dictionary gives both *cipher* and *cypher* in that order.

The preference for *cipher* over *cypher* seems to be a little greater in American English than in British English. The Corpus of Contemporary American English has just over three times as many records for *cipher* than it has for *cypher*. The British National Corpus has only one and a half times as many. It would not occur to me, as a speaker of British English, to use anything other than *cypher*.

Comment: In academia 'cipher' seems to be the popular choice even when the rest of a text adheres to British English spelling, though.

Comment: alright then, to decypher it is then  :-)

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: They are two valid spellings of the exact same word, but "cipher" is more common than "cypher".

Long answer:

I just came across [this page](http://blog.cipherprime.com/uncategorized/2013/05/its-cipher-prime-not-cypher-prime/), which is entitled ***It’s Cipher, Not Cypher***. It says:

> #### Where did the variants [of cipher] come from?
>
> The word we know today as cipher originated in the late 14th century
> from the Arabic word *sifr*, meaning “zero.” At this point in the
> English language (Middle English) the spellings of words were not yet
> explicitly defined, and writers commonly substituted *i*‘s for *y*‘s
> at will, hence the emergence of cypher as a variant for cipher.
>
> However, after the Great Vowel shift and the standardization of
> spelling in the 15th and 16th centuries, many of the y’s that denoted
> “eye” sounds in English were replaced by i’s–hence the change of “wyf”
> to “wife,” and “cypher” to “cipher.”
>
> [image]
>
> Even so, cypher is still considered a valid variant of cipher in many
> orthographic circles today. Cypher is most popular in England, where
> it first emerged.

---

Additionally, [this graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cipher,cypher&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,cipher;,c0;.t1;,cypher;,c0) from [Peter Shor's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147965/cypher-vs-cipher#comment305270_147966) shows how "cypher" was the preferred word until the early 19th century, when "cipher" became more popular. [This page](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=cipher,%20cypher&cmpt=q) shows that almost every country nowadays uses "cipher" over "cypher", with the exceptions being Ghana and Nigeria (and that's probably just from a lack of enough data).

Answer (score 4):

I have never come across *cypher* and I suspect that spelling is influenced by the y in *cyber*. Having said that, I do see one of the dictionaries I checked (Collins) giving cypher as an alternative.

In any case, you probably want to stick to cipher.

Even etymologically, the medieval Latin spelling was ciphra (from the Arabic sifr, which ultimately derives from Sanskrit śūnya!). So *cypher* even if used, is a less logical spelling for this word.

In contrast gray/grey seems to be a more established transatlantic (UK-US) divergence.

Comment: The standard spelling in the 18th century was *cypher*. [See the Google Ngram here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cipher%2Ccypher&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccipher%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccypher%3B%2Cc0). For etymology, the OED gives: *Old French cyfre, cyffre (modern French chiffre)*.

Comment: I see, I wasn't aware of that, thanks. But, most dictionaries I checked derive it in M.E from M.L ciphra.

Comment: The English would have been aware of both Mediaeval Latin and Old French. *Cypher* seems to have gotten the *"ph"* from Mediaeval Latin and the *"y"* from Old French, so both etymologies are justified.

Comment: The Arabic word does not derive from Sanskrit _śūnyas_; it is a translation of it. _Śūnyā_ is an abstract noun (derived from the adjective _śūnyas_ meaning ‘empty’), which denotes the number zero; the Arabic root _ṣ-f-r_ means ‘empty’, and from it, an abstract noun _ṣifr_ was created by analogy with the Sanskrit abstract noun to make a word for the notion of ‘zero’. This is what’s known as a calque.

Answer (score -2):

Cipher is a US-preferred variant of the generally accepted spelling. Both spellings are correct and of long standing. Both variants are also still in use in French.

Comment: In French? The French word is *un chiffre*. (Or *chiffrer* for the verb.)

Comment: In modern French, the word is "un cryptogramme" with a "y". Chiffre refers to a "digit" (0 to 9). However, "déchiffrer" does mean "to decipher" (with an "i", not a "y", btw). For historic reasons, one will use expressions like "le chiffre de César" (Caesar's cipher), but I doubt the average person would understand what "chiffre" refers to in such expressions (mathematicians and computer scientists would, to be fair).