# Cipher vs Cypher - British English vs American English

Tags: word-choice, american-english, british-english, orthography

As an English author but long time resident of America, I recently wrote a historical spy thriller that delved deeply into coded messages. I often caught myself writing *cipher* and *cypher*. Although I eventually used *cipher* exclusively the plot was mainly located in England and France.

Would *cypher* have been a better choice?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147965/cipher-vs-cypher

Comment: I would think that whether your readers were more likely to be North American or English, rather than the location might be the concern. Unless your characters are using the written word, in which case their culture would be the determinant.

Comment: In Britain from 1919 to 1946, the organization was the [Government code and cypher school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_Communications_Headquarters#Government_Code_and_Cypher_School_.28GC.26CS.29). So it would seem difficult to avoid *cypher* entirely.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't strictly an "answer", but I thought you would be interested to see this *pot-pourri* of spellings of *cipher/cypher* from the 16th century onwards. It is from sense 5 of the word *cipher/cypher* in the Oxford English Dictionary. Of course the word began life from the French *cuffre* (modern French *chiffre*) with an entirely different meaning (the figure, nought) in the 14th century.

> 5a. A secret or disguised manner of writing, whether by characters
>   arbitrarily invented (app. the earlier method), or by an arbitrary use
>   of letters or characters in other than their ordinary sense, by making
>   single words stand for sentences or phrases, or by other conventional
>   methods intelligible only to those possessing the key; a cryptograph.
>   Also anything written in cipher, and the key to such a system.
>
> 1528   S. Gardiner in N. Pocock Rec. Reformation I. No. 48. 92   We
>   think not convenient to write them, but only in cipher.
>
> 1587   A. Fleming et al. Holinshed's Chron. (new ed.) III. Contin.
>   1371/1   Letters betweene them were alwaies written in cipher.
>
> 1605   Bacon Of Aduancem. Learning ii. sig. Qq,   The kindes of
>   Cyphars..are many, according to the Nature or Rule of the infoulding:
>   Wheele-Cyphars, Kay-Cyphars, Dovbles, &c.
>
> 1652   J. Evelyn Mem. (1857) I. 289,   I had also addresses and
>   cyphers, to correspond with his Majesty and Ministers abroad.
>
> 1749   D. Hartley Observ. Man i. i. 15   We admit the Key of a Cypher
>   to be a true one, when it explains the Cypher completely.
>
> 1812   Duke of Wellington Dispatches (1838) IX. 235   We have
>   deciphered the letter you sent and it goes back to you with the key of
>   the cipher.
>
> 1837   A. Alison Hist. Europe VI. xlix. 508   Intercepting of some of
>   the correspondence in cipher.
>
> 1885   Gordon in Standard 24 Feb.   Cypher letter..which I cannot
>   decypher, for Colonel Stewart took the cypher with him.